# Android menu.xml unchanged after modifying file

Tags: android, xml, menu

This is driving my insane. I am inflating a layout using the following:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.location_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

When i modify the location_menu.xml file however and re-install the app nothing changes on the menu?!?

I can even completely delete the contents of the file and it makes no difference. The file is not duplicated in my project and I have searched the project and there are no other occurances of for example the name headings of the menus of icon references.

Im thoroughly confused what is going on please help

Comment: clean your project and then build its

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me a few times. If you're using Eclipse, try cleaning the project. This forces it to regenerate the R.java file and removes all cached files.

Comment: I tried that and its given me "R cannot be resolved" in every damn class!

Comment: @EHarpham what i your sdk version?

Comment: @EHarpham have you installed android sdk Build-Tools?

Comment: @Leon_SFS was working fine earlier and now I cleaned the project it wont build or run.

Comment: @EHarpham check xml file,if one of them getting error,the R File wont compile,sometimes not showing error on package explorer view,check all of them

Comment: @Leon_SFS Leon thanks for your help but I already checked that. Any other ideas?